# How to add new values into existing upperCase to new lowerCase

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am developing a method which takes ArrayList as an argument.
Then, the method makes some changes into the array and returns transformed arrayList.
The input array is going to be like that {A123, C123, 15B2} and I would like to get the following output {Aa123, Cc123, 15Bb2}.

That is to say, after any capital letter I need to add the same lowercase letter.

And there are any order and quantity of letters, e.g. it is also possible to get strings like those Hkjk124, hy71.

The method is shown below:

```
protected ArrayList<String> enrichValues(ArrayList<String> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        char[] charArray = list.get(i).toCharArray();

        List<Character> listChars = new ArrayList<>();

        for (char c : charArray) {
            listChars.add(c);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < listChars.size(); j++) {
            if (listChars.get(j).charValue() == 'A') {
                listChars.add(j + 1, 'a');
            }
        }

        String newChar = "";

        for (Character c : listChars)
            newChar += c.toString();

        list.set(i, newChar);
    }
    return list;
}
```

The main problem I have faced to is that I do not know how to check if a letter is uppercase.
I failed to apply something like:

```
if(Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
   listChars.add(j + 1, 'a');
}
```

Because of that I have to add lots of checks:

```
if (listChars.get(j).charValue() == 'B') {
    listChars.add(j + 1, 'b');
}
if (listChars.get(j).charValue() == 'C') {
    listChars.add(j + 1, 'c');
}
```

But it is a very bad approach. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can use ASCII value of alphabet to check the case

Comment: I don't understand, why did you fail to apply the `Character.isUpperCase(c)` method ?

Comment: I think that working with String.charAt(i) and Character.toLower() will work well for you. I answered below with a code example which worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way of doing it that works like a charm :

```
 public static  ArrayList<String> enrichValues(ArrayList<String> values){
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String str : values){ //For each string

        StringBuilder copy = new StringBuilder();

        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {//For each char

            copy.append(c);

            if(Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c)){
                copy.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
            }   
        }            
        array.add(copy.toString());
    }        
    return array;
}
```

Example :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "A123";
    String b = "C123";
    String c = "15B2";
    String d = " Hkjk124";
    String e = "hy71";
    String g = "AbCdE645 DeeeFFD";

    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    values.add(a);
    values.add(b);
    values.add(c);
    values.add(d);
    values.add(e);
    values.add(g);

    values = enrichValues(values);
    System.out.println(values.toString());
}
```

Output : [Aa123, Cc123, 15Bb2,  Hhkjk124, hy71, AabCcdEe645 DdeeeFfFfDd]

Comment: @YuryiKvashuk No problem :) Don't forget to accept it as the answer to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing some method which accepts concrete implementation of the `List` **interface** such as `ArrayList`, consider to change it to `List` type. This will allow you to pass in any form of list: `LinkedList`, `ArrayList`, ...

Another thing you shoud know is, that joining strings via `+=` is **inefficient**, as it creates `new String` instance each time `+=` is applied. Instead of doing this, you should use `StringBuilder` which allocates resizable buffer for string where you can append other characters.

Condition `Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c)` is **redudant**, since `Character.isUpperCase(char)` already returns `false` for non-letter characters.

If you need to convert character to lower-case use `Character.toLowerCase(char)`.

Note, characters are basically integers, so when you write something like this: `char c = 65;` and print the value, you will see 'A' in output, because 65 is ASCII value for character 'A'. If you add 32, you will obtain 97 which is 'a'. Putting all together you can write something like this:

```
char c = ...;

// c is in range of upper-case characters
if (c >= 65 && c <= 90) {
    char lower = c + 32;
}

// c is in range of lower-case characters
if (c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
    char upper = c - 32;
}
```

Try following method which mutates original list:

```
protected List<String> enrichValues(List<String> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(list.get(i));
        for (int j = 0; j < sb.length(); j++) {
            char c = sb.charAt(j);
            if ( Character.isUpperCase(c) ) {
                sb.insert(++j, Character.toLowerCase(c));
            }
        }
        list.set(i, sb.toString());
    }
    return list;
}
```

or this one which creates new list for transformed values:

```
protected List<String> enrichValues(List<String> original) {
    List<String> transformed = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
    for (String s : original) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        for (int j = 0; j < sb.length(); j++) {
            char c = sb.charAt(j);
            if ( Character.isUpperCase(c) ) {
                sb.insert(++j, Character.toLowerCase(c));
            }
        }
        transformed.add(sb.toString());
    }
    return transformed;
}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println( enrichValues(Arrays.asList("A123", "C123", "15B2")) );
// Output: [Aa123, Cc123, 15Bb2]
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out whether if a letter is upper case you just need to use the ASCII alphabet. Upper case characters go from 65 to 90.

So you just need to use a loop over the length of your string and check for each char if it´s ASCII value is between 65 and 90. So it would look like this, assuming the variable temp is one character of the string:

```
if((int)temp >= 65 && (int)temp <= 90){
//Add the lower case character by adding 22 to the character value (lower case are from 97-122)
char additionalChar = ((int)temp)+22;
}
```

Note that I´ve not tried the code so ((int)temp)+22 might not work that way, but it would look pretty similar.

Comment: Only works for the basic 26-letter Latin alphabet; `Character` has functions to find out all kinds of interesting thing about char values, including tests for upper- and lower-case that work on _all_ alphabets.  I18n, man!  It's the wave of the future! (;->)

Comment: True but comparing the ascii values is definitely the faster way^^

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this with regular expressions:

```
final ArrayList< String > outputList = new ArrayList<>();

for ( String str : list ) {
    final String[] letters = str.replaceAll( "[^A-Z]", "" ).toLowerCase().split( "" );

    final String result = String.format( str.replaceAll( "([A-Z])", "$1%s" ), letters );

    outputList.add( result );
}

return outputList;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work properly. 
By using the testing values from previous example {A123, C123, 15B2, Hkjk124, hy71,  AbCdE645 DeeeFFD} I got the following result [A123, C123, 15B2,  Hkjk124, hy71, AbCadEc645 DeeeeFdFfDf]
It is necessary to be - [Aa123, Cc123, 15Bb2,  Hhkjk124, hy71, AabCcdEe645 DdeeeFfFfDd]